# AMP warning as "An AMP component 'script' tag is present more than once in the document"

Tags: wordpress, amp-html, google-console-developer

I'm facing an issue the warning in AMP pages since last month as "**An AMP component 'script' tag is present more than once in the document.**".i tried to remove the duplicate script from the AMP, but cant able to find. i don't know weather it came from the plugin or somewhere else...

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here, read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Can you provide the code?

Comment: its not a code it just script which has pluggin added itself

Comment: filter the js file, can you share the link

Comment: @BachchaSingh Yes Here is link https://truweight.in/blog/weight-loss/6-interesting-health-benefits-of-drinking-hot-water-for-weight-loss.html/amp

Comment: Filter amp-form-latest.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stop the auto injection, simply add the following code to your functions.php

```
add_filter( 'amp_post_template_data', function( $data ) {
$data['amp_component_scripts'] = array_merge(
$data['amp_component_scripts'],
array(
'amp-iframe' => 'https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-iframe-latest.js',
'amp-analytics' => 'https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-analytics-latest.js',
'amp-sticky-ad' => 'https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-sticky-ad-latest.js',
'amp-form' => 'https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-latest.js',
'amp-ad' => 'https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-ad-latest.js',
)
);
return $data;
} );
```

Ref : [Click Here](https://www.patchworkoftips.com/fix-amp-script-errors/8415/)

Comment: will it be effected to the other pages if i add this filter

Comment: in that case you can put the check : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/